# Add nanoseconds to column of type TIMESTAMP(23,10)

Tags: h2

Given I have database column of type `TIMESTAMP(23,10)`, how can I add nanoseconds?

When I try:

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET VALID_TO = DATEADD('NANOSECOND', 999999999, VALID_TO);
```

or

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET VALID_TO = DATEADD('NS', 999999999, VALID_TO);
```

I get

```
Invalid value "NANOSECOND" for parameter "date part";
```

or

```
Invalid value "NS" for parameter "date part";
```

According to the [documentation of DATEADD function](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#dateadd), I should be able to use nanoseconds.

I'm using `com.h2database:h2:1.4.196`

Comment: Looks like a bug if it should support nanoseconds or unclarity in documentation if it shouldn't. It works up to milliseconds, i tried to hack it with setting it to millisecond and giving a value 1e-6, but it silently ignored it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is `com.h2database:h2:1.4.196` specific. It is not present in `com.h2database:h2:1.4.197`.

See [my github issue and answer from H2 maintainer](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/1575#issuecomment-442415626) for more details.